# PHP - issue while perform my sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an issue when I am trying to perform my query into my php script.

I need to update all columns of my table with `'QI'` when columns' values are `< 300` and with `'Validated'` when `> 300`.

Actually, queries are running but it seems it does the update several times.
Could tell me what I am doing wrong in my php script?

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    //Get column names and do the update
    $fields = mysqli_query($conn,'SHOW columns FROM '.$tablename.'AmpliconData');

    //columns to exclude
    $columns_to_exclude= array('Amplicon');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fields)) {
        $columns[]=$row['Field'];

        foreach ($columns as $ind=>$val) {
            if (!in_array($val,$columns_to_exclude)) {
                $sqlQI = 'UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$row['Field'].'="QI" WHERE '.$row['Field'].'<300;';

                echo $sqlQI.'<br/>';

                mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQI);

                $sqlVal='UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$row['Field'].'="Validated" WHERE '.$row['Field'].'>300;';

                echo $sqlVal.'<br/>';

                mysqli_query($conn,$sqlVal);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: _"but it seems it does the update several times."_ Well, you've placed your queries in a loop, so the queries will be executed each time the loop is run through...

Comment: @Epodax Updating the field names, isn't that a dangerous job doing through php.

Comment: I put queries in the loop because I get column names that I fetch into array `$row['Field'];`

Comment: @Plum I'm not sure I follow? He's updating the values, not the column names.

Comment: $sqlVal="UPDATE ".$tablename."AmpliconData SET ".$row["Field"]."='Validated' WHERE ".$row["Field"].">300;"; // i guess, don't shoot me if i am wrong but i thought sql wants ' not "

Comment: @Plum, yes I am updating values not column names

Comment: My bad guys.. carry on

Comment: Well, instead of executing the queries in your loop then store the fields you want to update in an' array and execute the queries outside of the loop, @Firewizz - Sql doesn't care in this instance, if at all.

Comment: not true, the RAW sql query of his contains fieldname="QI" and i thought is had to be  fieldname='QI' so there you need the ' not " but i am not 100% shure

Comment: @Firewizz, u are right my sql query contains fieldnames that I need to update. I tried outside the loop but I don't get columns names back

Comment: can u post the echo $sqlVal return where you echo'ed it

Comment: @Firewizz What? using `'` or `"` in most cases doesn't matter at all, in some cases you have to use _`_ for the column names, but again, in this case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @user979974 Store the column names in a' array and use the array in your queries outside of the loop.

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fields)) { $columns[]=$row['Field'];} foreach ($columns as $ind=>$val) { if (!in_array($val,$columns_to_exclude)) {
$sqlQI = 'UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$row['Field'].'="QI" WHERE '.$row['Field'].'<300;';
echo $sqlQI.'<br/>';
mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQI);

                $sqlVal='UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$row['Field'].'="Validated" WHERE '.$row['Field'].'>300;';

                echo $sqlVal.'<br/>';

                mysqli_query($conn,$sqlVal);
            }
        }` That's what I did but It didn't return fieldnames

Comment: @Epodax, Thx dude, the solution was as you adviced me, putting queries outside the loop. I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue. Putting the queries outside the loop was the solution.

Here's how I did:

```
$fields = mysqli_query($conn,'SHOW columns FROM '.$tablename.'AmpliconData');

//columns to exclude
$columns_to_exclude= array('Amplicon');


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fields))
{
$columns[]=$row['Field'];}
foreach($columns as $ind=>$val){

    if(!in_array($val,$columns_to_exclude))
    {
//$sqlAlterInt2Varchar='ALTER TABLE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData CHANGE '.$row['Field'].' '.$row['Field'].' VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL';
//mysqli_query($conn,$sqlAlterInt2Varchar);
$sqlQI='UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$val.'="QI" WHERE '.$val.'<300;';
//echo $sqlQI.'<br/>';
mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQI);

$sqlVal='UPDATE '.$tablename.'AmpliconData SET '.$val.'="Validated" WHERE '.$val.'>300;';
echo $sqlVal.'<br/>';
mysqli_query($conn,$sqlVal);
}}
```